# Running a console app programmatically whenever needed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, automation, job-scheduling

I have a C# console app that processes a queue (in db) and processes user uploaded contents.
It is running as a scheduled task.

If some user drops some content, the process won't pick it up until it is time for it to run.

If the job runs once every 5 minutes then it has to wait for max 5 minutes to run.
I want to process user content right away.

If user1 drops content and then user2 drops content after 30 seconds, I want 2 instances of my job running.

Is it possible to trigger the job\task to run from the C# code (MVC controller)?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially it sounds like you're just looking to perform an asynchronous operation.  Depending on the version of .NET, there are a number of options.  For example, the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) is a simple way to invoke an asynchronous operation.  So if the task is encapsulated into some object (for the same of example, let's say a method called `Process` on an object called `content`) then it might look like this:

```
var processContent = new Task(() => content.Process());
processContent.Start();
```

The task would then continue asynchronously and flow control would return to the application (which is particularly ideal in a web application where you don't want a user looking at an unresponsive browser, naturally).

If you're using .NET 4.5, you can also make use of [the `async` and `await` keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) to perhaps make it a little more clear.  At its heart, you're talking about running a process in [a separate thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e8s7xdd.aspx).

This all assumes that the web application and the console application share the same back-end business logic code.  Which, of course, is *probably* what they should be doing.  If for some reason that's not an option (and I recommend looking into making it an option), you can [start a process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) from code.  It could be something as simple as:

```
Process.Start("C:\Path\To\ConsoleApplication.exe");
```

Though forking all of these processes can look pretty messy and might be very difficult to manage in terms of error handling/logging/etc.  Another reason why it's best to keep the logic in the same process as the application, just in a separate thread.

Comment: I have an exe (console app) which I need to kickstart from C# code (MVC controller). What did you mean by "web application and the console application share the same back-end business logic code"?

Comment: @kheya: The business logic should be in its own assembly (class library project) and both applications should reference that assembly in the solution.  So when each application is deployed, it has its own copy of the business logic code.